PHP Stan error with return Union type in PHP v7, laravel
According to some conditions, I need to return int or Collection (the table data from mysql query or his count), Here is code what I did implemented.
public function myMethod(
        Term $term,
        int $id,
        ?bool $includeRecords = false,
        ?int $page = 1,
        ?int $count = 100
    ) {
        $currentDefaultSegment = Segment::DEFAULT_SEGMENTS[$id];
        $filterFieldName = $currentDefaultSegment['type'] === 'opener' ? 'lastOpenDate' : 'lastClickDate';

        $query = DB::connection(MYSQL_DB)
            ->table("my_table")
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('id', $term->getId())
            ->whereRaw("{$filterFieldName} > CURDATE() - INTERVAL {$currentDefaultSegment['duration']} DAY");
            
            if ($includeRecords) {
                return $query->limit($count)->offset(($page - 1) * $count)->get(); // It return Collection
            }

            return $query->count(); // It return int
    }

But when I use this method, php-stan complain and seems like it does not recognize when would be Collection or Int.
Error message: Cannot call method transform() on Illuminate\Support\Collection|int.
Here is code that is calling above method.
$this->myMethod(prams here)->transform(....) // In this case myMethod return type should be Collection instead of Int.
Question: How to determine & force return type is only Collection or only Int according to the Use cases?
I've tried make 2 methods instead of One according to the conditions, but Almost method body is the same, so I dont think it is good idea to make 2 methods. But have no idea how to solve the problem.

"I need to return int or Collection" - why not use two seperate methods for this requirement? How is this problem related to Laravel itself? Also, as you mention PHP 7 in the title: please keep in mind that this version is EOL since nearly two years

Can use seperate method, but 2 methods are really similar and almost same, so trying to  use one and implement logic according to condition. That's really old project and now under upgrading php version.

You can resolve this issue by using PHPDoc annotations to indicate the possible return types,  Use PHPDoc Annotations, specify the conditional return types by documenting that it returns either an int or a Collection based on the $includeRecords parameter. Before calling check what it is return Collection or int for example
/**
 * @param Term $term
 * @param int $id
 * @param bool|null $includeRecords
 * @param int|null $page
 * @param int|null $count
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|int
 */
public function myMethod(
    Term $term,
    int $id,
    ?bool $includeRecords = false,
    ?int $page = 1,
    ?int $count = 100
) {
  //Your logic here
 return $query->count();// It is return int
}


Shifoev, Hey there, Thank you for your answer. Well, actually, already I have PHPDoc annotation @return int|Collection, But still complain php stan error.
I was able to fix the problem by adding @phpstan-var Collection when I get the return result.
    /**
     *@phpstan-var Collection
     * */
    $collection = $this->myMethod(...)

